# Monitor everything that goes through my router-modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have spent days on google searching for what I need. I have found lot of forums but it has been difficult to understand them cuz of technical terms or abbreviations used.
I am not technie so please help me understand in simple words or lehman language how I can achieve what I need.

I have a Encore(ENHWI-2AN3) Wifi Router connected to cable modem (DOCSIS).
We connect couple of laptops, smart phone and tablets to this wifi.
I wanted to capture all the data(websites browsed, email content, facebook, whatsapp messages) that goes through the router.

How can I achieve it? I have heard getting tcpdump, using wireshark to read it but I never understood how to configure it.

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

TIA
-DJ

Comment: You can capture URLs of sites visited if your router has a SYSLOG feature enabled. This streams the web addresses visited to an IP of a SYSLOG server that can do whatever you require with the logs. The rest of what you're trying to do is almost impossible with your equipment. Most sites such as Facebook and WhatsApp use SSL which encrypts the content of things like messages sent across the site. The URL retrieved isn't so much of a problem but any form submissions (chat, comments etc.) there's no chance. If your email is via SSL (hotmail, Exchange, GMail etc.), too, then, again, no chance.

Comment: Be warned, however, not all modem/routers offer SYSLOG functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would try out couple of options suggested by Werner in the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a router behind a modem this is quite easy.

Some routers (like the FRITZ!Box) offer a web page where you can start a network capture. You will then get a file that you can open in Wireshark.

If your router does not implement such a feature, there is a second possibility. You can put a network switch between the router and the modem. If the switch allows mirroring one port to another, you can for example connect router to port 1, modem to port 2, a new dedicated capture PC to port 3 and set the switch to mirror all traffic on port 2 to port 3. Then the PC will see all network traffic. That PC should only be used for monitoring, not for sending any data. In case you have old technology around you can also use a network hub. (Dumb) Network hubs always send all data to every port, whereas (intelligent) switches only send data to the port where the receiver of the packet is connected.

Of course you can also take a PC with two network cards, connect the router to one network card, the modem to the other and configure the PC to bridge both network cards. Then all traffic from one card is transparently forwarded to the other and the PC can inspect any traffic.

Comment: Thanks Werner for your help and information. I would like to either getting a new router which have network capture capability or buy a network switch. Do you have any suggestion on economical and reliable router and switch?

Comment: @chirkut Sorry, I don't have a recommendation for you. At work I am using an HP switch 1810-8G, it supports port mirroring, but I have no comparison if other switches are better or cheaper.

Comment: I would suggest getting a router which works with dd-wrt, then leverage that software and the knowledge of the community.   In fairness though, you will not only need to sniff the packets (eg with wireshark, tcpdump or ntop), you will also need to MITM the SSL connections - which will break end-to-end security of the devices.